# Getting value from ssh command

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a script to clear the some files from a host(Host_1).
In another host(Host_2), I am doing an ssh to the script in Host_1.

Script in Host_1:

```
if [ condition here ]
then
    rm -r /folder #command to remove the files here
    b=$(df -k /folder_name| awk '{print $4}' | tail -1) #get memory after clearing files.
    echo "$b"
else
    return 1
fi
```

In Host_2, I am doing an ssh to Host_1.

```
mail_func()
{
val=$1
host=$2
if [ $val -ne 1 ]
        then
        echo "$host $val%" >> /folder/hostnames1.txt #writing host and memory to text file
else
        exit
fi
}
a=$(ssh -q Host_1 "/folder/deletefile.sh")
mail_func a Host_1
```

It returns blank here. No output. I tried to see if any output was coming at all to Host_2 by just doing an

```
echo $a
```

This returned me blank. I am not sure what I missed here. Please suggest to get the memory space as well from a single ssh command.

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement is used to set an exit code; it is not used as output for a variable assignment. If you want to capture a string as output then you're probably going to need to write it to standard output. A quick fix would be the following modification of your script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#    Script in Host_1

if [ condition here ]
then
    rm -r /folder #command to remove the files here
    b=$(df -k /folder_name| awk '{print $4}' | tail -1) #get memory after clearing files.
    echo "$b"
else
    # NOTE:
    #     This return statement sets the exit-code variable: `$?`
    #     It does not return the value in the usual sense.
    # return 1

    # Write the value to stdout (standard output),
    # so it can be captured and assigned to a variable.
    echo 1
fi
```

Comment: A filesystem could (in theory) have `1` available (or even a negative number) so `echo nofolder` or something might better distinguish `echo 1` from what `df` might return.

Comment: @thrig That's a good point. There are probably a few improvements that could be made here. I'm going to elaborate a little bit, but I'm debating how much to include without going to far afield.